# How to make terminal emulator using c++ and display the output in ncurses window?

Tags: c++, bash, boost, terminal, ncurses

```
#include "Terminal.h"


void Terminal::send_buffer_to_terminal(std::string buffer)
{
    input << buffer << std::endl;
    input << "echo " << delimiter << std::endl;
}

std::string Terminal::terminal_process(std::string command)
{
    bp::child p("/bin/bash", std::vector<std::string>(), bp::std_out > output, bp::std_in < input);  
    while(1)
    {
        command.clear();
        //get_input(command);
        //printw("Enter command")
        send_buffer_to_terminal(command);
        std::cout << command ;
        process_command(command, output, input, delimiter);
        //_terminal_display._input_buffer.erase();
        //_terminal_display._enter = true;
    }
    // p.terminate();
    p.wait();
}

void Terminal::process_command(std::string& command, bp::ipstream& output, bp::opstream& input, char delimiter) {
    if(command == "exit")
    {
        return;
    }
    //input << command <<std::endl;
    //input << "echo "<< delimiter<<std::endl;

    std::string line;
    std::getline(output, line, delimiter);
    _terminal_display.add_message(line);
    // refresh();
    char c = output.get();
    assert(c == '\n');
}
```

This is the code i have. now i have another function from which i have to call the active window which is the terminal window and here is the code for it :

```
void DisplayManager::run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        
        move(LINES-2, 2);
        getstr(_input);
        if(strcmp(_input, "EXIT")==0)
        {
            break;
        }
        
        if(strcmp(_input, "SWITCH")==0)
        {
            _active_window = _active_window == CHAT_WINDOW ? TERM_WINDOW : CHAT_WINDOW;
            move(LINES-2, 0);
            clrtoeol();
            continue;
        }
        if(_active_window == CHAT_WINDOW)
        {
            add_chat_message(_input);    
        }
        else if(_active_window == TERM_WINDOW)
        {
            while(1)
            {
            getstr(_input);
            mvwprintw(_term_display._window, 1, 2, "i");
            _terminal.terminal_process(_input);
            }
        }
        move(LINES-2, 0);
        clrtoeol();
        display();
    }   
}
```

so i need to make the boost child run throughout the time i am using term_window. any idea how i could make this work?

I tried the terminal code and it works individually , but somehow i cannot display it in the terminal ncurses window and it is throwing boost::process::error , what() execve failed :Bad address error whenever i enter a shell command.

what i actually want to happen is that when i enter bash commands , i need it to execute the commands and display the result in ncurses window.
btw, this is linux based.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a terminal emulator, for example with `libvterm`.

Then, the easiest way is to use `forkpty` instead of `fork` which correctly does `openpty`, `fork` and `login_tty` steps required to connect the child process to your terminal emulation.

In the child process make sure the TERM environment variable is set to the appropriate value.

In the parent process, until the child process exits, you need to

- Have async loops to process input/output between vt and pty master. This amounts to just reading whatever your receive, and pushing it to the terminal emulator (`libvterm` has `vterm_push_bytes` for that purpose).
- Idem to process vt input (`vterm_output_get_buffer_current` in `libvterm`).

As an example (not using Asio) I got https://github.com/cantora/ncte to build and run on my box. That could be a starting point.

### Out-Of-The-Box

If you're ready to start processes anyways, you should consider whether just launching an existing terminal emulator like xterm or gnome-terminal to run your child process in would not be a lot more straightforward